# Excel - Complex Index-Match to Look Up Multiple Values

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to do a pretty complex lookup on a table and return multiple values.

I need to take each `ID` as a group, if `Service Code` doesn't contain **Plus** or if it contains **Exception**, ignore it. If `Sales` and `Service` *don't* match, ignore it. Everything else, I need to output to a list.

I'm in way over my head and don't even know where to begin here.

---

In other words, on **Plus** service `Sales` and `Service` cannot match unless an **Exception** has been made. The A, B, C data doesn't matter at all, but it's there.

[image: What I'm looking to do]

Comment: Are you open to VBA solutions, or only Excel formulas?

Comment: VBA is perfectly acceptable.

I just figured it seems like the kind of thing that *should* be possible with formulas.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I took the challenge for VBA. I got a little bit confused about what you wanted where **Exception** is present, so currently if there is an exception it will skip that group entirely. Let me know if this isn't the behaviour you wanted. You may be right that a formula exists and probably makes this look stupidly over-engineered. Hopefully it can help someone though!

```
Sub CalculateList()
    Dim startRowCount As Integer: startRowCount = 2     'Row to start on
    Dim columnId As Integer: columnId = 1               'Column containing ID
    Dim OutputColumn As Integer: OutputColumn = 7       'Column to output into

    '------ Begin

    Cells(1, OutputColumn).Select                       'Selects the output cell, incase there are any successes

    Dim rowCount: rowCount = startRowCount              'Sets our start row count for the loop
    Dim RowsContainingId()                              'Array containing the row ID's matching the current ID of the loop
    ReDim RowsContainingId(1)
    Dim CompletedIds()                                  'Array containing the ID's that have already been done
    ReDim CompletedIds(1)

    Do                                                  'Begin loop
nextNumberStart:                                        'Label to go back to if we hit an already completed ID
        Dim CurrentID As String: CurrentID = Cells(rowCount, columnId).Value            'Get the CurrentID of this loop
        If (CurrentID = "") Then                        'If we hit a blank, we're done, so...
            Exit Do                                     'Exit the loop
        End If
        If (IsInArray(CurrentID, CompletedIds)) Then    'Check if this ID has already been handled
            rowCount = rowCount + 1                     'It has, so select the next row
            GoTo nextNumberStart:                       '...And begin the loop again
        End If

        GetAllMatchingRowIds CurrentID, RowsContainingId, startRowCount, columnId   'Runs sub lower down to populate the array with all the rows with this ID
        If (TestIdMeetsCriteria(RowsContainingId)) Then     'Test these rows to see if it meets your criteria (function below)
            ActiveCell.Value = CurrentID                'It's a success, so write this ID in our active cell
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate            'And select the cell one row down, ready to write again if needed
        End If


        CompletedIds(UBound(CompletedIds) - 1) = CurrentID      'Add this ID to our completed list
        ReDim Preserve CompletedIds(UBound(CompletedIds) + 1)   'Grow our array one more ready for next completed item

        Erase RowsContainingId                          'Wipe out our Matching ID array for next loop
        ReDim RowsContainingId(1)
        rowCount = rowCount + 1
    Loop
End Sub

Function IsInArray(stringToBeFound As String, arr As Variant) As Boolean
  IsInArray = (UBound(Filter(arr, stringToBeFound)) > -1)           'Checks if a string is in the array
End Function

Function TestIdMeetsCriteria(arr As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim row
    Dim HasException, ValidPlus: HasException = False: ValidPlus = False        'Set our bools to False
    For Each row In arr                                             'Loop through each row containing our ID
        If (LCase(Cells(row, 2).Value) = "plus") Then               'Check for "Plus" (case insensitively)
            If (LCase(Cells(row, 3).Value) = LCase(Cells(row, 4).Value)) Then   'We got Plus, do we have matching Service and Sales (case insensitive)?
                ValidPlus = True                                    'We do. Set ValidPlus to true for comparison later
            End If
        ElseIf (LCase(Cells(row, 2).Value) = "exception") Then      'Now check if any rows contains Exception (case insensitive)
            HasException = True                                     'We do. Set HasException to true for later comparison
        End If
    Next
    TestIdMeetsCriteria = Not (HasException) And ValidPlus          'We finished the loop. If HasException is still false, and ValidPlus is now true, it was a success, otherwise a failure
End Function

Sub GetAllMatchingRowIds(idToFind As String, arr As Variant, startRowId As Integer, columnId As Integer)
    Dim rowCount: rowCount = startRowId
    Do                                                          'Loop through our ID column rows
        If (Cells(rowCount, columnId).Value = idToFind) Then    'Check if the ID is the one we're after
            arr(UBound(arr) - 1) = rowCount                     'It is, add it to our array
            ReDim Preserve arr(UBound(arr) + 1)                 'Grow our array for next lop
        End If
        rowCount = rowCount + 1                                 'Next row
    Loop Until IsEmpty(Cells(rowCount, columnId).Value)         'Keep looping until we hit a blank
    ReDim Preserve arr(UBound(arr) - 2)                         'Remove additional entries in array we don't need
End Sub
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you right, you want the list as above, except you want to exclude ID codes if  the id's service codes don't include a plus. Additionally, if the sales and service do not match, they are not to be included - UNLESS there is an `exception` in the service code.

Have you thought about helper columns?

The easiest way to do this would be to concatenate columns A+B in column E, which would give you a row of id numbers and service codes.

You can then use a countif statement in row E to check for where `ID` and `PLUS` = `true`.

You'd then need to check names and exceptions.

You can then use a nested IF statement to check for Matches, Exceptions and Pluses.

In E it will obviously be `=CONCATENATE(a2,b2)`

F will look like this `=if(countif(E:E,CONCATENATE(a2,"PLUS"))>0,"PLUS","")`

G you'd need to use to check the names - so you'd need to go with `=Concatenate(a2,if(c2=d2,"Match","ERROR")`

H you'd need to use to check that the names are all OK or an exception exists.

`=if(and(countif(g:G,concatenate(a2,"ERROR")>0,NOT(countif(e:e,concatenate(a2,"EXCEPTION")>0))),"No match","match")`

finally, in I you can then look for where Plus = Plus and name match = Match

`=IF(AND(F2="Plus",H2="Match"),"Include","Exclude")`

This (if my formulae are correct- ymmmv!) should allow you to then filter the list by "INCLUDE", et Voila, your list of `ID` where `service` and `sale` is either `Exception` or matches, and at lease one of the `ID`'s service code entries contains `plus`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more flexible solution than VBA, however somewhat of manual workflow hybrid.

Add a `TRUE`/`FALSE` column titled "Serviced by Sales"

`=C2=D2`

Then another `TRUE`/`FALSE` column titled "Has exception"

`=COUNTIFS(A:A, A2, B:B, "Exception")`

Then you would simply filter the table where `Serviced by Sales = TRUE` and `Has exception = FALSE`. To get your list, you would copy and paste the IDs elsewhere and run a `Data > Remove Duplicates`.

If you are expecting real-time report generation of lists, I would defer to the VBA solution.